# Updating datetime returns error even after changing default language

Tags: sql-server, datetime

When I update a datetime

```
UPDATE client SET dt_modification='2012-05-13 19:16:40'
```

I get the following error :

```
    SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 242 - The conversion of a char data type 
to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

The reason is that the SQL datetime format I'm using (**YYYY-MM-DD**) is not corresponding to the expected one which is **YYYY-DD-MM**. Indeed, the following command is working :

```
UPDATE client SET dt_modification='2012-05-12 19:16:40'
```

The database I'm working on is a copy of another which has US default language and where the update is working. 
So I tried to change the server default language to US but it is not working. 
I used this command :

```
   sp_configure 'default language', 0
   reconfigure with override

--before change :  default language 0   9999    2   2
--after  change :  default language 0   9999    0   0
```

Anyone can help ?
Thank you

Comment: Use `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` format. So, you could try `UPDATE client SET dt_modification='2012-05-13T19:16:40' WHERE ...`.

Comment: Bogdan's comment is correct - don't try to fiddle with default conversion settings - use an *unambiguous* format (or, if you're working against the server from another programming language, use built in datetime functionality and avoid treating these as strings completely)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to change language settings for a single database, AFAIK. You can only do that for the whole server. However, you have several options: use

```
set date format YMD
```

when you start your sessions. Not very practical, though. You might also [recreate your login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) and set a default language there.